# Programmatically download an order report to a server in Odoo

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

Is there some kind of endpoint or get resource available to download a quotation_order printout report?

I was able to get account invoices with the following code from the Odoo docs:

```py
private void generateReport(final Object reportId) throws XmlRpcException, IOException {
final Object[] invoice_ids = (Object[])models.execute(
  "execute_kw", asList(
    db, uid, password,
    "account.invoice", "search",
    asList(asList(
      asList("type", "=", "out_invoice"),
      asList("state", "=", "open")))
  ));
final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl report_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
report_config.setServerURL(
  new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/report", url)));
final Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)models.execute(
  report_config, "render_report", asList(
    db, uid, password,
    "account.report_invoice",
    invoice_ids));
final byte[] report_data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(
  (String)result.get("result"));

File file = new File("proposal/odooOutput.pdf");
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(report_data);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, report_data);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to hit the quotation_order (sale.order) printout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this was my method for accomplishing this in Java:

```
private void generateQuotationOrderReport(final Object internalOdooQuoteId) throws XmlRpcException, IOException {
logger.info("generating quote report pdf for order #: " + internalOdooQuoteId);
final Object internalOdooQuoteIds = asList((Object[]) models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
  db, uid, password,
  "sale.order", "search",
  asList(asList(
    asList("id", "=", internalOdooQuoteId)
  )),
  new HashMap() {{
    put("limit", 1);
  }}
)));

final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl report_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
report_config.setServerURL(
  new URL(String.format("%s/xmlrpc/2/report", url)));
final Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)models.execute(
  report_config, "render_report", asList(
    db, uid, password,
    "sale.report_saleorder",
    internalOdooQuoteIds));
final byte[] report_data = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(
  (String)result.get("result"));

File file = new File("records/quotation_order.pdf");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, report_data);
}
```